# Object Becomes Number After Function Call - Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, animation, types, three.js

I am using Three.js to create an animation, but my `animate()` function is not working properly. Simplified code below:

```
let obj;
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, asp, near, far);
let scene = new THREE.Scene();
const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
async function init() {
    obj = await loader.loadAsync("./public/modelo/scene.gltf");
    scene.add(obj.scene);
    animate(obj.scene.children[0]);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    function animate(objeto){
        console.log(objeto);
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        objeto.rotation.z += 0.005;
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
}
init();
```

The function works for the first call, but after that I can see things going wrong via my `console.log()` statement. On the first run of `animate()`, the line prints out the object, as expected. But, on all ensuing calls, the statement just returns a floating point number that increases greatly with each successive call. I checked and made sure that the object was intact at the end of the first function call, so I'm not sure what's going on here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in this one line in your code:

```
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) for `requestAnimationFrame`, the callback you pass it - here `animate`, is:

> The function to call when it's time to update your animation for the next repaint. The callback function is passed one single argument, a DOMHighResTimeStamp similar to the one returned by performance.now(), indicating the point in time when requestAnimationFrame() starts to execute callback functions.

In other words, your `animate` is getting called with a timestamp - which in some ways I imagine behaves much like a number (I'm not personally familiar with what a `DOMHighResTimeStamp` is), and explains what you're seeing. It certainly won't be getting called with your "objeto" as argument.

To ensure that, just pass in as a callback a function will calls `animate` with the correct argument. Replace the call above with

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => { animate(objeto); });
```

EDIT: or as @Bergi suggests, we can avoid needing an argument at all by simply defining `objeto` outside `animate`, in the `init` function. Since you always call `animate` with this same argument there's no need to specifically pass it, so your code can just be:

```
async function init() {
    obj = await loader.loadAsync("./public/modelo/scene.gltf");
    const objeto = obj.scene.children[0];
    scene.add(obj.scene);
    animate();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    function animate(){
        console.log(objeto);
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        objeto.rotation.z += 0.005;
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
}
```

Comment: …or, much simpler, define `const objeto = obj.scene.children[0];` inside the `init` function and don't use a parameter in `animate` at all.

Comment: yes, that's a good point and would work too. I'll edit my answer to add this suggestion.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! Had been having all sorts of issues with this, and your answer worked perfectly. I should have clarified -- I simplified my code down but in my real file I am calling this function on multiple objects, so I prefer your method to making a variable so that I do not clutter my code with tons of functions.